# is the set of the elements of cantor set which are not rational uncountable?

Tags: abstract-algebra

is the set of the elements of cantor set which are not rational uncountable?

I'm thinking about that since cantor set is uncountable, so no matter it is rational or irrational, the subset of all elements of cantor set is not rational.

is it right? I feels like something wrong..

also is the set cantor set X the set of rational numbers uncountable?
since cantor set is uncountable, so there are uncountably pairs in the set?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking.  Yes the Cantor set is uncountable, from which it follows that it must contain some irrationals.  It could contain rationals or not, you can't decide that by counting.  Is that what you are asking?

Comment: I'm asking the set (cantor set / the set of the rational numbers), is it uncountable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Cantor set $E$ is uncountable; the rationals $\mathbb Q$ are countable, so $E \cap \mathbb Q$ is countable.  Since $E = (E \cap \mathbb Q) \cup (E \cap \mathbb Q^c)$, and
the union of two countable sets is countable, $E \cap \mathbb Q^c$ must be uncountable, i.e. there are uncountably many irrational members of the Cantor set.

EDIT: 
Yes: $E \times \mathbb Q$ is uncountable.  If  $B$ is nonempty, the cardinality of $A \times B$ is at least that of $A$, because if $b \in B$, $A \times \{b\}$ is a subset of it which is in one-to-one correspondence with $A$.

Comment: get it! thank you

Comment: I just edit the question with adding one more question. Could you help me with that as well? Appreciate!